# Can properties like color and font be set on konsole command line?

Tags: konsole

Hi:  I am exploring the possibility of using konsole instead of xterm to run a terminal session, mainly because I believe it might give me a broader set of color options.  But I don't know if it's possible to set things like colors and font on the command line when invoking konsole.

What would be great is something like this...
konsole --fg=#ff00ff --bf=#00ff00 -fn= (etc...)

What would be just as good is if I could create and post a profile (as a file) and reference that.  Something like...
konsole --profile=/proj/settings/the_konsole.profile

What I can't have is setting colors with a gui tool.  The konsole is going to be created for users and they won't have the time/interest/knowledge to play with that stuff.

If the first option is viable, can I specify the color using the hex representation as in the example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works...

Create a profile using the gui 
 -> Settings -> Manage profiles -> New profile -> Etc...
For me, the profile file appeared in... ~/.kde/share/apps/konsole/MyProfileName.profile

Then, just call it out when you invoke konsole...
konsole --profile ~/share/apps/konsole/MyProfileName.profile

Seems to work.

One other thing I discovered...
WHen trying to set the size of the terminal it creates, use --geometry="widthxheight".  E.g. --geometry="1000x500"
You also need to use --nofork to get this to work right.

Hope this helps someone.